# FullCalendar - Timezone does not work

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/) to power up my calendar app. 
And I have spent three hours trying to understand why FullCalendar would ignore my timezone setting. The interesting thing is that if I change `Europe/Moscow` to `local`, then everything works. 
Is there something I am doing wrong or is this a bug of FullCalendar ?

https://jsfiddle.net/9y8ecw1q/

Comment: what result were you expecting on your calendar instead of what is shown? It's not entirely clear. Your event data does not carry any timezone information on it. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/ says of the specific zone option: "Use this mode if you store timezone information for your events and you want them displayed in a timezone that can be customized."

Comment: If you study the timezone demo https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.8.2/demos/timezones.html you'll notice that when the timezone is changed via the dropdown the calendar asks the server for new event data, and the server re-sends the event data with new timezone offsets in the start/end parameters. Your timezone setting will have no effect unless you do this.

Answer (score 2):

[Fullcalendar docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/) tell it, though it is a bit hard to find....

Under 'Timezone string, look at 2) (in bold, though not really strongly separated to easily see...)

> 2) Your server-side script is then expected to use the timezone parameter to calculate the timezone offset of the returned ISO8601 dates!

The key thing here is that, in order for this to work, you must be using server-side scripts.

Comment: You mean that the datetimes should already be in the right timezone?

Comment: No, it just means that, if you want to set these as timezones, you need to use server-side processing.  Using 'local' is 'common' as the user will see the date in their own time (which is usually best for things like conference calls, etc.), though if you are using server-side processing, you might want to use data with timezones.  Basically, using 'local' is for most implementations - the other choices are 'special case', depending on your overall setup, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with this problem for weeks..   I have figured out how to make it work in the client so that a new event can be displayed in any timezone without any server calls..

You need to include the four-moment timezone plugins, 2 from the moment site and 2 from the full calendar site in this order.

https://codepen.io/alexgrant999/pen/gOOWLdb?editors=0010

```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var initialTimeZone = 'UTC';
  var timeZoneSelectorEl = document.getElementById('time-zone-selector');
  var loadingEl = document.getElementById('loading');
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'momentTimezone','interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
    timeZone: initialTimeZone,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json',

    select: function(info)
                    {

          thestart = calendar.addEvent({
          title: "Session",
          //constraint: 'businessHours',
          start: info.start,
          end: info.end

          });


                    },

    loading: function(bool) {
      if (bool) {
        loadingEl.style.display = 'inline'; // show
      } else {
        loadingEl.style.display = 'none'; // hide
      }
    },

    eventTimeFormat: { hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit', timeZoneName: 'short' }
  });

  calendar.render();

  // load the list of available timezones, build the <select> options
  // it's highly encouraged to use your own AJAX lib instead of using enter code hereFullCalendar's internal util
  FullCalendar.requestJson('GET', 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-timezones.json', {}, function(timeZones) {
    timeZones.forEach(function(timeZone) {
      var optionEl;

      if (timeZone !== 'UTC') { // UTC is already in the list
        optionEl = document.createElement('option');
        optionEl.value = timeZone;
        optionEl.innerText = timeZone;
        timeZoneSelectorEl.appendChild(optionEl);
      }
    });
  }, function() {
    // failure
  });

  // when the timezone selector changes, dynamically change the calendar option
  timeZoneSelectorEl.addEventListener('change', function() {
    calendar.setOption('timeZone', this.value);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled a lot with that as well. FullCalendar is using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) internally. Whenever the dates of an event are serialized to be stored i.e. with a PHP app, you need to know that times are in GMT/UTC. You may then trensfer that to your local TZ. In contradiction to that, FullCalendar expects any date set in the browser i.e. to create an event from data picked from an ajax call to be in the browsers TZ.